# Can elasticsearch percolator give word position?

Tags: elasticsearch

I understand that there is term vector in elastic search which can give the word position and other stats.

Can percolator give the word position in the documents that are being searched on?
I understand that the documents are not indexed and only percolator queries are indexed. I see the below

```
If the requested information wasn’t stored in the index, it will be computed on the fly if possible. Additionally, term vectors could be computed for documents not even existing in the index, but instead provided by the user.
```

in - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html
So interested to know if elastic search can calculate the word position on the fly?

Any leads are appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaveh

Thanks for taking time for me but really sorry I don't see how this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67926555/4068218) is related because using artificial documents I can get the stats - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/docs-termvectors.html
but what I have is percolator - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2Ru2KV0DZg

So even if I get the term vector on fly using artificial documents or by the /_analyze it does not matter as they will not give me the position of terms (in percolator)

eg Percolator - I am trying to find the word - Hello.
My document has the below field and value
"text": "Hello World"

If I used artificial documents or /_analyze it will say 0 - Hello 1- World but when I percolate I will get the
percolate query that found the word Hello. I want to combine both and want the percolator tell
"I found Hello in position 0"

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the documentation for term vector if you store `_source` the Elastic can calculate the term vector on fly. It will analyze your text based on the source and it will aggregate it with existing term vector of index.
If you want to get the result for term you always can get your analyzed data for list of terms for more information [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

Comment: I see types of highlighters are unified, plain, and fvh but I dont see how these are related to my question on Percolation?  Looks like for fvh highlighter it needs "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets" to be specified while indexing but in percolator I do not index documents at all. So how this is related?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient please check my updated answer.